# How to convey turning something into something else, without using pronouns?

Tags: pronouns

I'm trying to figure out the proper grammar for conveying that something is turning something into something else, without using pronouns. Consider this:

> Socrates poisons the tranquil **so that they become** rabid.

I don't want to use the word **they**, or any other pronoun for that matter, because I think it sounds a bit pedestrian (this is part of a quasi ye olde english poem).

Would the phrase below be a valid alternative?

> Socrates poisons the tranquil **as to become** rabid.

It sounds okay to me, but I'm pretty sure it's not proper grammar. Any suggestions?

Comment: With poison, Socrates makes the tranquil rabid.

Comment: Was referring to Socrates corrupting the youth in ancient Athens by means of making them think and reason, i.e. not using actual poison :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. More like: Socrates poisons the tranquil **so as to become** rabid.

Comment: Ah! **So as to become**. I like it. Also, Microsoft Word complains, telling me to use concise language, so I guess we're on the right track since this is a poem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Socrates poisons the tranquil **so as to become** rabid.

The OED uses this phrase in [many of its definitions](http://www.google.com/search?q="so+as+to+become"+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fen.oxforddictionaries.com), even if it does not list it directly.

[Developable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/developable):

> (of land or property) able to be adapted or improved **so as to become** productive or profitable.

[Merge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/MERGE):

> Blend or cause to blend gradually into something else **so as to become** indistinguishable from it.

[Relax](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/relax):

> Rest or engage in an enjoyable activity **so as to become** less tired or anxious.